# Meaning of TfidfVectorizer toarray() and HashingVectorizer

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to understand vectorizer in python..
I'm using this example code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
# list of text documents
text = ["The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.", "The dog.", "The fox"]
print(text)
# create the transform
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
# tokenize and build vocab
vectorizer.fit(text)
# summarize
print(vectorizer.idf_)
# encode document
vector = vectorizer.transform([text[0]])
# summarize encoded vector
print(vector.shape)
print(vector.toarray())
print(vectorizer.vocabulary_)
```

The output is this:

```
['The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.', 'The dog.', 'The fox']
[1.69314718 1.28768207 1.28768207 1.69314718 1.69314718 1.69314718
1.69314718 1.        ]
(1, 8)
[[0.36388646 0.27674503 0.27674503 0.36388646 0.36388646 0.36388646
0.36388646 0.42983441]]
{'the': 7, 'quick': 6, 'brown': 0, 'fox': 2, 'jumped': 3, 'over': 5, 
'lazy': 4, 'dog': 1}
```

I don't understand why vector.toarray() produce duplicate number for different word..for example there are 0.36388646 four times..and 0.27674503 two times..what does rapresent this number?
The number that the neural network use to train it self are those printed with vectorizer.vocabulary_?

With hashing vectorizer instead I have this code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer
# list of text documents
text = ["The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."]
# create the transform
vectorizer = HashingVectorizer(n_features=20)
# encode document
vector = vectorizer.fit_transform(text)
# summarize encoded vector
print(vector.shape)
print(vector.toarray())
```

And that's the output:

```
(1, 20)
[[ 0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.33333333
 0.         -0.33333333  0.33333333  0.          0.          0.33333333
 0.          0.          0.         -0.33333333  0.          0.
-0.66666667  0.        ]]
```

Is the 0. value used? What rapresent? And why even there it prints duplicate values? (0.3333333 and -0.33333333)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You see duplicate numbers in the first case because you have multiple words in your "corpus" that have identical IDF (inverse document frequency). For example, the words *dog* and *fox* have the exact same pattern of occurrence in your text, so they have the same IDF; these two are represented by the  1.28768207 values. The word *the* occurs in every text, so it's represented by the 1. The rest of the words in the vocabulary occur once in the first text and not in the other two, so they all have the exact same IDF. You can see which feature corresponds to which word with `vectorizer.get_feature_names()`.
- With HashingVectorizer, you have chosen the number of features to be 20, but the total number of unique words in your text is less than 20, so you will have a lot of features which are 0. You get less than 8 non-zero elements because there are some hash collisions - that's because 20 is way too few features to avoid collisions (consider that the default is 2^20). If you choose a higher `n_features`, you will get exactly 8 non-zero elements. You have duplicate values because, once again, almost all the features have identical frequencies in that text.
- And for the question in your title, the [`toarray()` method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.toarray.html) converts the efficient representation of a sparse matrix that sklearn uses to your ordinary readable dense ndarray representation.

Answer (score 0):

> TfidfVectorizer()

converts a collection of raw documents to a matrix of TF-IDF features.
you are running

> vectorizer.fit(text)

only
i suggest you run

> vectorizer.fit_transform(text)

then it tokenized your text created a features for your text. since your text have 8 features (**{'the': 7, 'quick': 6, 'brown': 0, 'fox': 2, 'jumped': 3, 'over': 5, 
'lazy': 4, 'dog': 1}**
it returned you 8 frequencies corresponding to them. you can also cross verify it by running

> print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())

which will give you
**['brown', 'dog', 'fox', 'jumped', 'lazy', 'over', 'quick', 'the']**

> print(vectorizer.fit_transform(text).shape)

will give you

> (3, 8)